# link of the website from where url is redirected

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have a link http://ucut.herokuapp.com/1g. if anyone clicked this link from twitter or facebook ,how can I get the website name from where the link has been redirected

Comment: You can get it (sometimes) from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it's not reliable to the point where personally I wouldn't even bother with it.

Comment: I am creating a url shortner website. i need to show that how many clicks from facebook, twitter e.t.c. How to do this? any idea ?

Comment: check this one, might help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-referrer-url

Answer (score 0):

You can use native php's `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` or Laravel's `Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');`